# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when giving access to new folder

Tags: c#

I am using below code to grant access to IIS Folder:

```
string path=@"C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC6\";
AddDirectorySecurity(path, "everyone", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account, Rights,
    ControlType));      
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

}
```

Comment: This code should be run as a privileged user (ex: Administrator).

Comment: i have written this code in console application. you mean to say i should run this console as administrator right?

Comment: Yes. (I hope it is not a production IIS server)